# PHP> echo string separated by lines of 3 words each?

Tags: arrays, string, echo, explode

I need make something that includes a function that uses explode to create an array. I have seen several examples, but near the end I really get confused! Is there a simple readable way for this? (//comments?)

Take for instance a piece of text:

```
"This is a simple text I just created".
```

The output should look like this:

```
This is a
simple text I
just created
```

So the explode should split the text into lines of 3 words each.

Comment: I think we may need some more clarification here. What are you trying to explode, and what are you trying to do with the array after?

Comment: I don't understand question, what do you exactly need?

Comment: Sorry, take for instance a piece of text> "This is a simple text I just created".

The output should look like this:
This is a
simple text I
just created

So the explode should split the text into lines of 3 words each.

Comment: What kind of peace, you need to array of words from text or what?

Answer (score 1):

Try this is what you need:

```
<?php

$text = "This is a simple text I just created";

$text_array = explode(' ', $text);

$i = 1; // I made change here :)
foreach($text_array as $key => $text){

 if(ceil(($key + 1) / 3) != $i) { echo "<br/>"; $i = ceil(($key + 1) / 3);  }
 echo $text.' ';
}
?>
```

Result:

```
This is a
simple text I
just created
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = "This is a simple text I just created";
$text_array = explode(" ", $text);
$chunks = array_chunk($text_array, 3);
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    $line = $impode(" ", $chunk);
    echo $line;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `substr()` function [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Example:

```
<?php
$rest = substr("abcdef", -1);    // returns "f"
$rest = substr("abcdef", -2);    // returns "ef"
$rest = substr("abcdef", -3, 1); // returns "d"
?>
```

In your case:

```
<?php 
$rest = substr("This is a simple text I just created", 0, 15); //This will return first 15 characters from your string/text

echo $rest; // This is a simpl
?>
```

Comment: Well it should be a single echo, can I archive this using substr()?

Comment: Really handful, but I think I did not explain myself.
What I need is to split the text in lines of 3 words each, so the text output would be fully visible such as this:

This is a[lineBreak]
simple text I[lineBreak]
just created[lineBreak]

Sorry I can't Space lines here, I edited the question above.

Answer (score 0):

explode just splits the string at a specified character. There's nothing more to it.

explode(',', 'Text,goes,here');

This splits the string whenever it meets a , and returns an array.

to split by a space character

explode(' ', 'Text goes here');

This splits only by a space character, not all whitespace. Preg_split would be easier to split by any whitespace

Comment: I see, but how can I echo an array as a paragraph like this one?

This is a
simple text I
just created

Comment: well, you'd need to loop through the array using a foreach. But looking at the new comments you've made, using this method you would also need an incremental counter and an if to check after every third word whether you'd need a new line. but this may not be the most efficient way to do it

Answer (score 0):

So something like...

```
function doLines($string, $nl){
  // Break into 'words' 
  $bits = explode(' ', $string);
  $output = '';
  $counter=0;
  // Go word by word...
  foreach($bits as $bit){
     //Add the word to the output...
     $output .= $bit.' ';
     //If it's 3 words...
     if($counter==2){
       // Remove the trailing space
       $output = substr($output, 0, strlen($output)-1);
       //Add the separator character...
       $output .=$nl;
       //Reset Counter
       $counter=0;
     }
  }
  //Remove final trailing space
  $output = substr($output, 0, strlen($output)-1);

  return $output;
}
```

Then all you have to is:

```
echo doLines("This is a simple text I just created", "\n");
```

or

```
echo doLines("This is a simple text I just created", "<br />");
```

..depending if you just want new lines or if you want HTML output.